# How to get text from selected value in a dropdownlist which is js based

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dropdown

Hello i have trouble getting the value out of a dropdownlist created with the plugin FacetWP. I have searched A LOT and tried a lot of different methods to get the text value out of that list but with no success. my latest try was:

```
var messagepop = $(".facetwp-filter .facetwp-facet-perioxeskalipsis > .fs-label-wrap > .fs-label").text();
            alert (messagepop);
```

I have no idea what else to try.. i tried siblings() find() and everything other but i was getting a blank box in the alert..any help would be appreciated!

UPDATED: problem was due to an ajax request taking place at the time. Had to place the code a few lines further down!

[image: Code]

Comment: `facetwp-filter` what is this? A class or an element?

Comment: you are right its a class but the problem remains

Comment: _"This is a picture of the code to help out"_ - relevant code belongs directly into your question, not as screenshots on external sites. Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$('.facetwp-filter').find('div[data-name="perioxeskalipsis"]').find('div.fs-label-wrap').find('div.fs-label').text();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it doesnt do the trick unfortunately. it gives me a blank alert box

Comment: @ΣταύροςΓιούτσος Just check you are getting any thing back `$('.facetwp-filter')`

Comment: if i use for example this   
var messagepop = $(".facetwp-facet-perioxeskalipsis").attr("data-name");  it actually gives me back the correct value

Comment: @ΣταύροςΓιούτσος if you are doing `$(".facetwp-facet-perioxeskalipsis").attr("data-name");` then you are receiving data?

Comment: @ΣταύροςΓιούτσος Try this  `$(".facetwp-facet-perioxeskalipsis").find('div.fs-label').text();`

Comment: i found the problem! when you load the page or when you switch selection there is an automated ajax request running. Your code and my code was right all along so I had to place the code in a later stage of the process. Thanks for your support though! cheers

Comment: @ΣταύροςΓιούτσος Welcome buddy :)